# media 2.x: customize media browser view with single fields - how to submit media item?

Tags: views, media

I want to use 7.x-2.x-dev as it uses a view as media browser. I added several fields (license, tags etc.) and want to show some of them in the media browser.

In the view, I thought of using an unformatted list instead of the "media browser" style plugin; but of course, now the items either 
- cannot be selected for submission (if I disable their links) or
- are linked to their content

How can I mimic the normal beaviour (clicking on a media item just selects it for inserting)?

Thanks in advance to everyone,
sol